# Product of sets as complexes

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, binary-operations

What does it mean to take the product of two sets of complex numbers as complexes?

Reading this paper: "The Determinant of the Sum of
Two Normal Matrices with Prescribed Eigenvalues" by N. Bebiano and J. F. Queiro

Here's the paper:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379585902319/pdf?md5=4ad22968e71962565f02aeaad8f27c8b&pid=1-s2.0-0024379585902319-main.pdf

It refers to products of sets as complexes. Here's a quote

> LEMMA 1. If $S$ and $T$ are subsets of a real algebra, then $(\operatorname{conv} S)\cdot (\operatorname{conv} T)$ is a subset of $\operatorname{conv}(S\cdot T)$. [Here $X \cdot Y$ means the product (as complexes) of the sets $X$ and $Y$.]

$\operatorname{conv}$ means convex hull.

I don't understand what kind of product of sets this is.  I suspect it is related to topology.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what tags would be relevant either (except [tag:terminology]). Thing is, Ameet, "the product (as complexes)" means the set of all products, $$X \cdot Y := \{ xy : x \in X, y \in Y\}.$$

Comment: Okay, one irrelevant tag removed, one relevant tag added. Would be nice to find more tags we could add, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer, hmm...so the "as complexes" means nothing more than them being sets of complex numbers?

Comment: @AmeetSharma No, not complex numbers. The lemma says "subsets of a real algebra". That algebra might happen to be $\mathbb{C}$, but usually isn't. I'm not sure why the terminology is as it is, but the set of sums/products of two subsets of a thing with addition/multiplication is sometimes called the "complex sum/product", or the "sum/product of complexes".

Comment: @DanielFischer And in another context it's the ["Minkowski sum"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From p. 22 of B. L. van der Waerden, *Modern Algebra*, Volume I, Revised English Edition, Frederick Ungar Publishing Co., New York, Copyright 1949, 1953:

> In group theory a *complex* is defined as an arbitrary set of elements of a group $\frak G.$
>   
> By the *product* $\frak{gh}$ of two complexes $\frak g$ and $\frak h$ we understand the set of all products $gh$ where $g$ is taken from $\frak g,$ and $h$ from $\frak h.$ If in the product $\frak{gh}$ one of the complexes, say $\frak g,$ consists of only one element $g,$ we may simply write $g\frak h$ instead of $\frak{gh}.$